# How to seek() then pause() with JWPlayer 5.4

Tags: jwplayer, seek

Does anyone know how to get JW PLayer v5.4 (either the Flash rendering or the HTML5 rendering) to pause after a seek() command?

I'm trying to get the video to step 0.01 seconds forward or backward when a user clicks the fine-grain control buttons (or uses the left or right arrow keys). This is so they can snap a framegrab with better precision.

I'm not sure if this is even possible but I've tried a few things with no luck. Such as the following:

```
var stepTo = jwplayer("video_player").getPosition() + 0.01;

jwplayer("video_player").seek(stepTo).onComplete(function(){
    jwplayer('video_player').pause();
});
```

And:

```
jwplayer("video_player").pause().seek(stepTo);
```

And:

```
jwplayer("jwplayer_container").seek(stepTo).pause();
```

And:

```
jwplayer("video_player").pause().play().pause();
```

I've also seen that the 'Shortcuts' plugin has this feature, but that plugin ins't compatible with v5.4 yet.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

@AJB -

There's [a ticket](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/ticket/1119) to add an "onSeek" event scheduled for the 5.6 player.  In the meantime, the best way to do this is probably something like this:

```
jwplayer("video_player").seek(stepTo);

var pauseOnSeek = true;
jwplayer.onTime(function() {
   if (pauseOnSeek) {
      this.pause();
      pauseOnSeek = false;
   }
});
```

If the onTime() event fires off before the seek is complete, you may be able to hack around it by setting a timeout before defining the onTime() handler.

Comment: No dice PabloS, I tried it but it just kept going back to the "frame" it was initially paused on and then pausing there again. Didn't step forward. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I'm still not clear about the use of onTime function. The lecture that I do is: Do things while the video is playing (on the time the vid plays)...is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

With JW Player 6, you can do the following to cause the video to pause after seeking:

```
jwplayer("vidPlayerDiv").onSeek(function () { jwplayer("vidPlayerDiv").pause(); });
```

Comment: This didn't work for me because it seems that onSeek() is not invoked for the first time you call seek(). Ended up using onPlay().

Answer (score 0):

This is a little variation on PabloS code:

```
jwp = var player = jwplayer('target').setup({
    file: '/some-file.mp3'
});

jwp.seek(position);

var pauseOnSeek = true;
jwp.onTime(function () {
    if (jwp.getState() === "PLAYING" && pauseOnSeek) {
        this.pause();
        pauseOnSeek = false;
    }
});
```

I had to write code that changed source mediafile without starting video from the beginning. I wanted to handle switching video when it was paused. When I used `seek` and `pause` in `onSeek` callback it didn't work because video was still buffering. Pausing in `onTime` callback like in code above worked like a charm.

Comment: old comment but you can use this: `jwp.on('time', callback)`