# JW Player 6 seek and pause

Tags: javascript, html, flash, video, jwplayer

How can I get JW Player 6 to seek to a point and pause itself there without losing the ability to seek while continuing playback on subsequent requests.

For example, the following solution is not satisfactory because it pauses the player after every seek request, not just the current one.

```
var player = jwplayer('target').setup({
  file: '/some-file.mp3'
});

player.onSeek(function(){
  player.pause();
});

player.seek(300);
```

Really, I'm looking for an API which is as simple as this:

```
player.seek(toTime, pause = false)
```

Note that there is a similar [open question referring to JW Player 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4771470/574190).

Comment: Do you have an example of where you did this?

Comment: Hey David, were you ever able to figure this out? I'm having trouble with the same thing. I can't get JWPlayer6 to intelligently retain its playing or paused state after seek

Comment: Nope. I think the project ended up going in a different direction before I could come up with a fix.

Comment: @DavidTuite : Searching for same thing ? have you got solution for it

Comment: @hitesh Nope. Never found a solution. Ended up using the [SoundManager2 library](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using attributes of HTML  Tags.
Example:

```
<audio ontimeupdate="tracktime(this)" id="audio" preload="none" controls="controls" width="300" onplay="javascript:onplay()" onpause="javascript:onpause()" onended="javascript:onended()" src="">

<script>
var mediaElement = document.getElementById('audio');

mediaElement.seekable.start();  // Returns the starting time (in seconds)
mediaElement.seekable.end();    // Returns the ending time (in seconds)
mediaElement.currentTime = 122; // Seek to 122 seconds
mediaElement.played.end();      // Returns the number of seconds the browser has played
</script>
```